# Display field from referenced entity using Display Suite and Views

Tags: views, entities, display-suite, nodes

I have a view which displays some products (node) teasers.

In the products, I can select a producer (taxonomy term).

Now... In the products teasers I want to display the country, which is a field from the producer taxonomy term. How can I add this field to the teaser using Display Suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure a new view mode for vocabularies (admin/structure/ds/view_modes). Let's call it "country"

Then on your newly created view mode (admin/structure/taxonomy/{tax_name}/display/county) configure the fields you want to show. In your case this will be the term name and the country.

After you done that you have to go to the manage display of your product content type and select the "teaser" view mode. There, on your taxonomy field, choose "Rendered taxonomy term" as format. Then click the button on the right and choose "country" as view mode.